# Check if grunt is installed?

Tags: gruntjs

I have Node JS installed. How can I check if grunt is installed? Is it installed globably or does it reside in a specific folder?

For instance, `node -v` will tell me I have `v0.10.33` installed but I cant find any similar commands for Grunt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check the Grunt version by using `grunt --version` or `grunt -V` (uppercase 'V')

[Grunt command line interface (CLI) options](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#version-v)